# Inconsistency between Lighthouse report FCP and Performance tab FCP

Tags: performance, google-chrome, lighthouse

I have a website built on Next.js and it's pretty fast so I'm a bit surprised by Lighthouse's bad score. When I check the report it says FCP is 3.8s in.

[image]

But when I click "View Original Trace" I'm taken to the performance tab and the timeline says FCP is 91.9ms in:

[image]

Which one should I trust ? Why those differences ? Am I reading it wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64792982/2702894

Comment: Yes it does! thank you. The question should be marked as duplicate/related then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LCP time between LightHouse and Performance - Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791933/lcp-time-between-lighthouse-and-performance-google-chrome)

Comment: No problem, I don't like to just mark things as duplicate in case there is something different about people's question I have missed. I have marked it now!

Comment: thanks for that :)