# How do I understand if my web app has a good performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-web-vitals, web-vitals

I am using reportwebvitals in react to gather performance-related data. I see values such as:

```
{name: "LCP", value: 865.895, delta: 865.895, entries: Array(1), id: "v1-1619568902884-5783450530819"}
{name: "FID", value: 3.389999968931079, delta: 3.389999968931079, entries: Array(1), id: "v1-1619568902884-3190618744586"}
```

I understand that a good LCP score is below 2.5sec and a good FID score is below 100 ms. Given the values which key exactly indicates this score?

I tried to go through the available documentation but was not able to understand how to derive these time results. Can somebody please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be based on [web-vitals.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals). The README has a lot more information about how to interpret the output and when to use `delta` versus `value`. To answer your question, the `value` field tells you the scores for each metric:

LCP = 866 milliseconds

FID = 3 milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Google Lighthouse chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk?hl=en) and test performance, accessibility, best practice and SEO for your project.

It will test your project and guide you how to improve the performance including LCP.

Here's the [reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse)

And also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791933/lcp-time-between-lighthouse-and-performance-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

A good and fair metric would be to test your page via Google's [PageSpeed Insights.](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) This would give you a detailed overview of miscellaneous web vitals, for both mobile and desktop devices. Here's an example of [Stackoverflow's web vitals](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com):

[image]

The great aspect of GPSI is that it assigns a score to your page's website, and gives you great feedback on how you could potentially improve your score.

Answer (score 0):

Your FID and LCP score is a value calculated based on performance represented as a `DOMHighResTimeStamp`. 
The documentation contains information about how this is calculated, where the data is saved, and more information prevalent to your question.